# Como cancelo un commit y traigo cambios de otra rama local

Tags: git

Estaba realizando una tarea en una rama `feature/CW166` y para probar diferentes plugins, cree nuevas ramas locales. Terminé trabajando en una llamada `feature/CW166-test-rdr`. En ella completé la tarea para la cual cree la rama `feature/CW166`, y cree un commit.

Lo que yo quisiera hacer es lo siguiente

- Volver a mi rama `feature/CW166` a la cual le habia commiteado los cambios antes de crear la rama `test-rdr` y cancelar el ultimo commit, luego empatarla con la rama `develop`, y finalmente traer los cambios de mi rama `test-rdr` a `feature/CW166`, para pushear esta ultima.

CREO que deberia hacer

```
git checkout feature/CW166
git reset --hard HEAD^
git pull origin develop
git pull feature/CW166-test-rdr
```

> Pero tengo serias dudas si este es el procedimiento correcto. Alguien me podria confirmar o corregir? Muchisimas gracias

Comment: otra opcion que me sirve es eliminar la rama ``feature/CW166``, y renombrar ``feature/CW166-test-rdr`` a ``feature/CW166``, para posteriormente pushearla. Pero lo que quiero asegurarme es que no haya cambios en la rama develop para que funcione a la primera el pull request. No se si soy claro, me confunde un poco git

Comment: ¿Cuál es la razón para cancelar el último commit? pues yo solo uniría ambas ramas y continuo con el proceso normal de unión con `develop`, si nos da un poco más de contexto, le podríamos ayudar de mejor manera.

Comment: @DonovanPardo En el ultimo commit que quiero eliminar, el plugin que intentamos usar modifico a la fuerza la version de React de mi package.json, entre otros varios cambios que se realizaron. No estoy seguro de unir ambos cambios, ya que sospecho que este puede resultar en futuros inconvenientes. Perdon, si me dijeras cual es la informacion que puedo darte, con gusto lo hago. Ya te digo, al tener una idea muy basica de GIT crei que habia dado suficiente informacion. Las disculpas del caso.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo `feature/CW166-test-rdr` se creó a partir de `develop` por lo que no comparte los cambios efectuados en `feature/CW166`, por lo que yo haría es descartar por completo la rama `git branch -d <branch>` y renombraría `git checkout feature/CW166-test-rdr` ... `git branch -m feature/CW166`

Comment: @DonovanPardo muchisimas gracias, eso va a solucionar el problema. Te puedo hacer una ultima pregunta? Como puedo saber a partir de que rama inicial se creo otra rama local? (supongo que la inicial es la que estoy parado a la hora de crear la nueva rama, pero como puedo saber esto luego de creada la nueva rama). Mil gracias por todo!

Comment: @DonovanPardo y todavia tengo una ultima duda. Supongamos que hago un pull a la rama principal (develop), todo esta actualizado. Creo una nueva rama y empiezo a trabajar en ella. Supongamos que alguien hizo cambios en develop mientras yo trabajaba en mi nueva rama. Como puedo hacer un merge local entre mi trabajo y lo que hay en develop, para commitear todo junto y pushear la nueva rama, que tendria los cambios recientes de develop + los cambios que hice en esta nueva rama? Para la proxima pregunta dejame tu cbu x las dudas jaja

Comment: No es algo sencillo, una manera es `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph` que genera un pequeño gráfico  donde se puede llegar a ver de donde salió cada rama y sus respectivos commit

Comment: Yo antes de cruzar datos entre mi rama `feature` y mi rama de `develop`, lo que hago es un `git pull origin develop` (desde mi rama `feature/CW166` traigo los cambios realizados en el servidor a `develop`) y ahí si hago el **merge request** o el procedimiento que se realice interno para unir features con develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasarse a la rama donde están los cambios:

```
git checkout feature/CW166-test-rdr
```

Elimina la rama donde se realizaron cambios indeseados:

```
git branch -D feature/CW166
```

Renombra la rama `feature/CW166-test-rdr` a `feature/CW166`:

```
git branch -m feature/CW166
```

Actualiza con los cambios de `develop`:

```
git pull origin develop
```

Comment: Gracias por todo :)

Answer (score 0):

Un `git reset --soft` te debería ahorrar dolores de cabeza si lo que quieres es básicamente hacer un `squash` de las 2 últimas revisiones de esa rama

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "blah blah.... los cambios en una sola revisión."
```

Luego pon el apuntador de la rama "oficial" que quieres aqui:

```
git branch -f feature/CW166
```

Luego puedes hacer checkout de esa rama y borrar la otra.

Otra receta completamente diferente podria ser

```
git checkout feature/CW166
git restore feature/CW166-test-rdr
#asumiendo que hay un solo commit en feature/CW166 desde que se s3paró de su upstream
git commit --amend -m "los cambios de un solo guamazo"
```